# How to send email using Nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send a mail in my email id which is present in the database but I didn't receive it.
Mail in my email id when I am hitting API and got error `Missing credentials for "PLAIN"??.

```
forgotpassword: async (req, res) => {
        let { model } = req.body
        let email = req.body.email
        let emailsend = (email,firstName,token)=>{
            let trans = nodeemail.createTransport({
                 host: "smtp.gmail.com",
                  port: 465,
                  secure:false,
                  requireTLS: true,
                  auth:{
                   user:config.emailUser,
                   pass:config.emailPassword
                  }

            })
          let  mailoptions = {
                form: config.emailUser,
                to: email,
                subject: "for  reset password",
                html: '<p>hii' + firstName+ ', please copy the link <a href= "http//:localhost:5001/resetpassword?token='+token+''>"</a>reset your password"
            }
            trans.sendMail(mailoptions , (err, data) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    console.log("mail is sent",data.response)
                }
                
               
            })
        }
let  mailoptions = {
                form: config.emailUser,
                to: email,
                subject: "for  reset password",
                html: '<p>hii' + firstName+ ', please copy the link <a href= "http//:localhost:5001/resetpassword?token='+token+''>"</a>reset your password"
            }
            trans.sendMail(mailoptions , (err, data) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }else{
                    console.log("mail is sent",data.response)
                }
                
               
            })
        }
```

Out as a like receive mail in my gmail id but didn't. Can anyone tell where I am mistaken?

Comment: auth:{
           user:config.emailUser,
           pass:config.emailPassword
  }
this user and pass should be correct

Comment: Have you set up SMTP access to your gmail account? By default gmail will block all SMTP access to gmail accounts unless it has been set up. You either need to get an OAuth token for your app/script or configure your gmail account to be less secure.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are using the wrong SMTP email and password. your mail password and SMTP password are not the same. I'm using `nodemaler` like this with Gmail SMTP. and its working fine.

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
async function sendEmail(to, subject, message, htmlMessage){

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "your_smtp_host", port: 'smtp_port', secure: true, auth: {
            user: 'smtp_mail', pass: 'smtp_pass'
        },
    });
    await transporter.sendMail({
        from: "from_email_address",
        to,
        subject,
        text: message,
        html: htmlMessage,
    });
}
```